# How can i implement Notifications system in django

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates, django-signals

I created an app where user's can post a question and get answers from others users.
Now I want to implement a notification system, so that when a user answer a question, the author of that question will receive notification. Like social media notifications.

The home templates:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <a href="{% url 'question' %}" class="btn btn-primary  m-1">Ask Question</a>
                <a href="{% url 'notification' %}" class="btn btn-primary  m-1">Notifications</a>
                <a href="{% url 'FeedBack' %}" class="btn btn-primary  m-1">FeedBack</a>
                <a href="{% url 'login' %}" class="btn btn-primary  m-1">Log Out</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

 <div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        {% for question in list_of_question reversed %}
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="card my-3">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <p class="card-title">{{question.user.username.upper}}</p>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <a href="{% url 'view-Question' question.id %}" style="text-decoration: none;">
                        <p class="card-title">{{question.title}}</p>
                    </a>
                    <p>Category: {{question.category}}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        {%endfor%}
    </div>
</div>
```

the models:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, null=False)
    body = RichTextField(blank=False, null=False) 
    category = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False, null=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.title)

class Answer(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=False, null=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    answer = RichTextField(blank=False, null=False)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Question, blank=False, null=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user)
```

The views:

```
class My_Question(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Question
    fields = ['title', 'body', 'category']
    template_name = 'question.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('index')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        return super (My_Question, self).form_valid(form)

class My_Answer(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Answer
    fields = ['answer']
    template_name = 'answer.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('index')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        form.instance.post_id = self.kwargs['pk']
        return super (My_Answer, self).form_valid(form)

def viewQuestion(request, pk):
    question = Question.objects.get(id=pk)
    answers = Answer.objects.filter(post_id=question)
    context = {'question':question, 'answers':answers}
    return render(request, 'viewQuestion.html', context)
```

the home page view:

```
@login_required(login_url='login')
def index(request):
    query = request.GET.get('q', None)
    list_of_question = Question.objects.all()
    if query is not None:
        list_of_question = Question.objects.filter(
            Q(title__icontains=query) |
            Q(category__icontains=query)
        )
    context = {'list_of_question':list_of_question}
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

the urls

```
path('index/', views.index, name='index'),
path('view/<int:pk>/', views.viewQuestion, name='view-Question'),
path('question/<int:pk>/answer/', views.My_Answer.as_view(), 
name='answer'),
path('question/', views.My_Question.as_view(), name='question'),
```

Comment: What is the problem with your code? Does your print statement not run (It should show up in the console) when you add an answer?

Comment: Yes it's showing on my console. But that is not what I need. I want it to be like: **when you answer someone question the author of that question would be able to get notifications** like how we get notifications in **stack overflow** or how we received notification when someone **likes** or **comments** something on our social media accounts.

Comment: You need to write code to do that obviously... Maybe you can have a model where you store all the notifications for a user query that and display them, maybe you just want a one time notification in that case you can use the [messages framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/messages/). If you want your question answered you need to clarify your question more and also narrow the scope, building an entire notification system might not get you answers on Stack Overflow

Comment: The message framework only works with the current user, you instead want to send notifications to the author of the question so you'll have to use a model to store notification data.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is an outline for a basic notification system in Django:

### Model

You need a model to store notifications. Each notification belongs to a user and has content (i.e. a text message). You also need to store whether a message has been read and a timestamp:

```py
class Notification(models.Model):
    is_read = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    message = models.TextField()
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

### Creating a notification

You can then create a new notification for a user when needed, e.g. when another user answers a question you can also create a notification for the question's owner in the view.

```py
class My_Answer(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    ...
    def form_valid(self, form):
        ...
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        question_author = form.instance.post.user
        Notification.objects.create(user=question_author, text="New answer!")
        ...
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

### List of notifications

Then you need a page that lists all notifications for the current user. That can be implemented with a standard list view.

The query would look something like this:

```py
class NotificationListView(ListView):
    model = Notification

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Notifications.objects.filter(user=self.request.user).order_by("-timestamp")
```

You of course also need to define a URL and a template for this new view. We will define the URL name as `notifications`.

### Showing new notifications to users

Finally, you need to inform users about new notifications. This can be done by checking how many unread notifications the current user has and showing a badge on the web badge. This would be part of the index view.

```py
@login_required(login_url='login')
def index(request):
    ...
    unread_notifications = Notification.objects.filter(user=request.user, is_read=False).count()
    context["unread_notifications"] = unread_notifications
    ...
```

Then on your home page you need a link to a page that shows all notifications and a badge that shows how many unread notifications the current user has. Something like this:

```html
<a href="{% url "notifications" %}">
  Notifications
  {% if unread_notifications %}  
    <span class="badge bg-secondary">{{ unread_notifications }}</span>
  {% endif %}
</a>
```

### Real life example

If you want to see how this is implemented in a real project, here is the link to an open source project called "Alliance Auth" that implements a portal web page and has a very similar notification architecture. The link is to the notification app within that portal: https://gitlab.com/allianceauth/allianceauth/-/tree/master/allianceauth/notifications

Comment: it throws me an error sir ** class NotificationListView(ListView):
TypeError: Table.__init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 4 were given**

Comment: i have added the **template_name = 'notification.html'** inside **class NotificationListView(ListView):**

Comment: I solve the problem by importing **Django.views.generic.list import ListView** but when I click on **notification** in home template it's throws me an error: **cannot resolve keyword 'order_by' into field. Choices are: id, is_read, messages, timestamp, user, user_id,**

Comment: After I added this  line: **question_author = form.instance.post.user
        Notification.objects.create(user=question_author, text="New answer!")**  in to my **My_Answer** view it also throws me an error like this: **Answer has no post**

Comment: Hey, I fixed the order_by clause

Comment: sorry sir another error from my **index template** the home template: **Cannot resolve keyword 'is_unread' into field. Choices are: id, is_read, message, timestamp, user, user_id**

Comment: I fixed the line. If you have your project on github or gitlab I'd be happy to help you fix the last bugs directly. Might be easier then through comments.

Comment: okay sir this is my github repo link:   https://github.com/drivemetech/question

Comment: I send you the github repo sir

Comment: Let us continue the discussion on github: https://github.com/drivemetech/question/issues/1#issuecomment-1134920967

Answer (score 3):

To create a notification system in Django, you'll need to follow these general steps:

1. Create a notification model in your Django application to store notifications:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.urls import reverse

class Notification(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    message = models.TextField()
    link = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True)
    read = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

2. Create a view function to handle the notification logic, in this case:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from .models import Notification

@login_required
def notifications(request):
    notifications = Notification.objects.filter(user=request.user).order_by('-id')
    return render(request, 'notifications.html', {'notifications': notifications})
```

3. Add a signal to trigger the notification function when a user posts an answer:

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.urls import reverse
from .models import Notification, Answer

@receiver(post_save, sender=Answer)
def comment_post_save(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    user = instance.post.user
    message = f'{instance.user} answer your question on "{instance.post.title}"'
    link = reverse('post_detail', args=[str(instance.post.id)])
    notification = Notification(user=user, message=message, link=link)
    notification.save()
```

4. Create a notification template to display the notification message in notification.html page:

```
{% for notification in notifications %}
    {% if not notification.read %}
        <div class="notification">
            <a href="{{ notification.link }}">{{ notification.message }}</a>
        </div>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

create a views that shows how many of your question is geeting an answer:

```
def dashboard(request):
    unread_notifications = Notification.objects.filter(user=request.user, read=False).count()
    return render(request, 'dashboard.html', {'unread_notifications': unread_notifications})
```

dashboard template:

```
<a href="{% url "notifications" %}">
  Notifications
  {% if unread_notifications %}  
    <span class="badge bg-secondary">{{ unread_notifications }}</span>
  {% endif %}
</a>
```