# Django signals returns Notification.user must be a "CustomUser" instance

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-signals

I'm trying to use [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76171411/21835997) to add a Notifications system to my Django app. I want to notify our users when the `Invitation` model is created. However, the problem is that the `Invitation` model does not have a `user` field, and we don't want to add the `user` field to the model, because we don't want to make the person who is going to create the `Invitation` model a `user`, How can I notify user that one of his `Invitation` model is created, the method I'm using down below return an error: `Cannot assign "<Invitation: Adamu>": "Notification.user" must be a "CustomUser" instance.`

the signals:

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.conf import settings
from .models import Level, Notification, Invitation
from django.urls import reverse

User = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL

@receiver(post_save, sender=Invitation)
def comment_post_save(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    message = f'{instance.first_name} has booked our"{instance.select_type.level} room"'
    link = reverse('Open-Room', args=[str(instance.select_type.slug)])
    notification = Notification(user=instance, message=message, link=link)
    notification.save()
```

models:

```
class Invitation(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    id_card = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=ID_CARD)
    id_number = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    nationality = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=LIST_OF_COUNTRY)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    town = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=90)
    phone_number = models.IntegerField()
    guardian_phone_number = models.IntegerField()
    number_of_day = models.IntegerField()
    visited_for = models.CharField(max_length=40, choices=VISITED_FOR_THIS)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    select_type = models.ForeignKey(LevelType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.slug:
            # generate a random 15-character string
            random_string = ''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits, k=15))
            self.slug = f"{slugify(self.nationality)}-{random_string}"
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.first_name)

class Notification(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    message = models.TextField()
    link = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True)
    read = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class LevelType(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

Comment: Several users could have the same firstname. How should that work?

Comment: @Marco you are correct. It may caused an error when the same `firstname` is created. I edited my question now.

Comment: @Marco When I try to locate the type of invitation one has submitted through the `link` in the `Notification` model, it may raise an error like: `multiple object has the same first_name` it can't redirect me to the exact object because of multiple object with the same first name.

Comment: As long as you dont have the user in the Invitation model you can not use it in the Notification model.

Comment: @Marco how about `Notification(user=instance.select_type.user, message=message, link=link)` it is working, but it redirect user to the some page instead of `Open-Room` in the link.

Comment: No idea what `select_type` is. Share the model.

Comment: The `select_type` is in the `Invitation` model check again.

Comment: Sure, but share the `LevelType` model.

Comment: @Marco Check the question again.